# How to use System.js with CDN and local fallback?

Tags: ecmascript-6, jspm, systemjs

I ran `jspm install angular` and it installed it locally to my jspm_packages folder.

From code, I use regular ES6 imports like `import angular from 'angular'`.

What do I need to do in order to load angular from a CDN and fallback to a local version if the CDN is unavailable?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, at least not without doing it yourself somehow (effectively replacing SystemJS)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have different `config.js` files for development and production, where the production one gets angular from a CDN while development gets it locally.  However, there is not (as far as I know) currently a way to have SystemJS try one source, then if that fails fallback to another source.

```
System.config({
    "map": {
        "jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the config.js would look like pointing to a CDN?

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't solve the fallback issue, but gives me an idea of how it would work.

Comment: @Natan what did you figure out in the end, can you post?

Answer (score 0):

I would you suggest to create an adapter module for angular:

local-repo/angular.js

```
define(function() {
    return window.angular;
});
```

Like this you can use your config file for deployment and production.
In production you simply make sure that you load angular first:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>`
systemjs code..